# PHP file_put_contents returns value but it does not write in the file

Tags: php

I have a `PHP` file and I've used `file_put_contents` function to write a string in a file:

```
<?php

$res=file_put_contents("/tmp/log.txt", print_r('test', TRUE), FILE_APPEND);

print_r($res);

$check = file_exists("/tmp/log.txt");

print_r($check);

?>
```

When I call my `PHP` file from browser the result of `$res` is 3 and it shows that the string is written in `log.txt` in `tmp` directory. The result of `$check` is 1 and it shows that file is made but when I check `tmp` directory, log.txt does not exist. I also checked `PHP` error log file but no error was logged there.

When I call the `PHP` file in server as `php /var/www/html/file.php`, the result is 3 1 and the file exists in `tmp`.

Comment: Try `getcwd() . "/tmp/log.txt"` for both your file paths

Comment: May be you're looking at the wrong directory for the text file.

Comment: `$res` should be 4, not 3 (the number of bytes in `test`), but otherwise the output of the code seems sane. I've run your code and the file is written on my machine. What server command are you using to check the `tmp` directory? Is there some other process that alters it?

Comment: @ChrisLear I use `ls` command

Comment: @SalmanA no. I'm sure about the directory.

Comment: `ls /tmp/log.txt`

Comment: @ChrisLear ls: cannot access '/tmp/log.txt': No such file or directory

Comment: @BrettGregson It didn't work

Comment: Did you check it in `/var/log/` directory

Comment: I get  permission denied

Comment: What does `echo realpath("/tmp/log.txt")` give you?

Comment: @SalmanA The result is /tmp/log.txt

Answer (score 2):

Login as root (sudo su OR so) and do this:
`find / -name "log.txt"`

You'll find this file in some folder like:
`/tmp/systemd-private-d0606967f7ad46d88c2298c8ce9ae2b8-php-fpm.service-uVTqqf` `/tmp/log.txt`

You'll find logs there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

```
<?php

$res=file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/tmp/log.txt", print_r('test', TRUE), FILE_APPEND);

print_r($res);

$check = file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/tmp/log.txt");

print_r($check);

?>
```

Comment: I checked it. It does not print any thing and does not make the file.

Comment: Please replace `FILE_APPEND` with `FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX` and try again. for more details http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: Did you check to Write permissions of `tmp` folder?

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: `ls -a`. To display hidden files

Answer (score -1):

Use the full path of the directory rather than using an absolute path.

`file_put_contents(full_path_to_your_filr_location, "text", FILE_APPEND);`